# Typescript does not see imported variable in generic type declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create a generic repository for every entity in the application

`mongo-repository.ts`

```
import { Document, Model, Types } from 'mongoose';

type MongooseModel<T> = Model<T & Document>;

export abstract class MongoRepository<T extends MongooseModel<T>> {
  protected constructor(
    protected readonly model: T,
  ) {}
}
```

`user.repository.ts`

```
import { User } from '../../../models/User';
import { MongoRepository } from '../../common/mongo/mongo-repository';

class Repository extends MongoRepository<User> {
  constructor() {
    super(User);
  }
}

export const UserRepository = new Repository();
```

Actual results:

```
src/modules/user/repository/user.repository.ts:4:42 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'User'.

4 class Repository extends MongoRepository<User> {
                                           ~~~~
```

Expected result:
Work.

However, I'm not getting this error message in `super(User)` but only in the generic declaration

Comment: are you sure you have exported your user model as named export not default export ?

Comment: `export const User = model<IUser, IUserModel>('User', userSchema);`

I'm sure about that

Comment: But, when I remove the import, and ask webstorm for suggestions it shows me totally different results in `super(` and in `MongoRepository<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,
Fix:

```
MongoRepository<T extends typeof Model>
class Repository extends MongoRepository<typeof User>
```